# Get an entity reference's field values in its field template

Tags: entities

I have an entity reference field and the template `field--my-custom-entity--field-my-entity-reference.html.twig`

In the template I print the content.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

**How do I print fields created on this entity reference field?**

Despite wishful thinking, this does not work: `{{ item.content.field_my_field }}`, nor does any of the 100 other possibilities I tried. Twig `dump()` was not helpful.

Comment: Don't do it! Use proper entity and field templates, use the same method for your referenced entity as you do on your normal host entity. Entities are cached render arrays, you would be bypassing a lot of security and performance logic built into Drupal core.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Are you just trying to print a couple fields from the referenced entity?

Comment: @sonfd Yes, in particular I'm wanting to add a class that includes the entity ID.

Comment: Not quite sure about the downvotes. Maybe it's not clear what I'm asking but it I don't see how it's in any way unreasonable to want to access fields on an entity reference field. This is a "proper" field template. It's a field template for an entity reference. Not sure how your concerns apply to my question @Hudri.

Comment: @John What you are trying to do is against Drupal's architecture and bad practice. E.g. when you view/render a node with a referenced entity, Drupal creates 2 cachable render arrays: one for host entity, one for the referenced entity. When the title of the host entity is changed, only the render array of the host entity is cleared, but the referenced one is safe for cache-reuse. I can't see any reason why to "hack" the host field, instead of using the proper templates and render arrays.

Comment: There are situations where this hack has its use-cases (e.g. design/logic that depends on data from multiple different fields). If you have a use-case like this, better go "one level down" in the render pipeline and change the referenced entity's node template (this would be "cross-field", but not "cross-entity" --> cache-safe, access control still intact)

Comment: @Hudri You are saying the answer I've accepted below is a "hack" and I shouldn't do it?

Comment: berramou's answer is correct and works... but I also I don't recommend it, because it is "cross-entity" rendering and this very often causes problems with cache.

Comment: Yeah you should be using a view mode instead. So, in the referencing entity display settings set to display the referenced entity in a certain view mode you configured earlier, and in this view mode display only the fields you need. All just simple site building while keeping the admin UI intact. Templating for this should be considered bad practice. It's difficult to maintain in the long run and circumvents the admin UI. The future maintainer of your project then can't simply click and change things from the UI but has to search through templates to find out where exactly this comes from.

Comment: To add just a class you are better off preprocessing that into the attributes. As a rule of thumb only do templating when you really need to change the markup (even this can often be accomplished with the Field Group module).

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying here. There's no way we could use the admin ui and view modes alone to build this site, which is from a robust parts kit of probably 100+ different components, with multiple classes on every html element. Not to mention classes that wire up Javascript for tabbed units, sliders, accordions, etc. The templating system and custom entities is the the only feasible/sane way to do it. If I were simply spitting out some text from a wysiwyg, then maybe view modes and {{ content }} in a template could do the trick. That's rarely the lack of complexity I'm afforded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the entity reference's field values:

1. Change the display of your field to **Rendered Entity** like the following
   [image]
2. Now you have access to your entity values in your twig inside `item.content` for example if your entity reference on content you will find `#node` key inside  `item.content` array for example you can render `field_my_field` like the following.

```
     {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content['#node'].field_my_field.value }}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Update:**
In case of custom entity change ***#node*** by ***#my_entity_type***

Comment: This works thanks. In my case it was `item.content['#my_entity_type'].field_my_field.value`

Comment: Any thoughts on comments above saying to NOT do this?

Comment: It's still not clear what your goal is. You say you want to add a class with the entity id, but which entity id (parent or referenced) and where do you want to add the class? You want to avoid changing something inside the referenced node here because caching strategies don't expect it. If you try to change something inside the referenced node on one page, and then the same referenced node is rendered on a second page, the cached version from the first page will be used on the second page. This is the caching issue @Hudri is mentioning above.

Comment: My goal is to add a class with the entity-id around every item in a multi-value entity reference field. The entity reference can reference any number of bundles. So rather than put this wrapper class in 10+ bundle templates, I want to put it in one place. My use case goes deeper, but that is a sufficient explanation. As I see it, I can do this 1 of 3 places. 1. The 10+ bundle templates (not ideal) 2. The parent entity template (not ideal, I have to loop through and render the entity references one by one. 3. The entity reference field template, which you are advising against.

Comment: Further, from what you're saying, I can surmise that even having that entity ref field template in my codebase is a bad idea? Because regardless of whether or not I access fields in it, it's still printing {{ content }}.

Comment: I don't follow your logic above. In a way you're saying don't use entity templates because caching strategies don't expect it? I wonder are we talking about disparate things here. Not sure if it's relevant, but none of this is dealing with nodes. It's all custom entities created with Drupal console.